# Java automatically connect to server if it opened

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming

I'm trying to create a program which will determine if the server is connected, down or disconnected.
I need to make the client automatically connect to the server when it's open.

Questions:

`1. How can I continuously ping the server, to determine if the server is up?`

`2. Why is it when I click the button the server can only receive once.`

`3. Determine when the Server is disconnected`

here's my code:

**SERVER**

```
   public Server()
    {
        super("Server");
        server.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        main.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        top.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        bot.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        console.setEditable(false);
        console.setFont(new Font("Courier New",Font.PLAIN,14));
        console.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        console.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        bot.add(console);
        top.add(btnReply,BorderLayout.EAST);
        top.add(queryline,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        main.add(top,BorderLayout.NORTH);
        main.add(bot,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(main);
    }

    private void runServer() throws IOException
    {
        int port = 25000;
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        console.setText("Server is Up and listening to the port: "+port+"\n");
        System.out.println("Server is Up and listening to the port: "+port+"\n");

        while(true)
        {
            Thread thread = new Thread(new Handler(socket));
            thread.start();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
        Server f=new Server();
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        try
        {
            f.runServer();
        }catch(IOException ex)
        {
            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {

    }
}

class Handler implements Runnable 
{
    private Socket socket;
    public Handler(Socket socket){
        this.socket = socket;
    }

    public void run() 
    {
        // You may need to add a repeat and exit clause here...
        Server f=new Server();
        try
        {
            InputStreamReader ir = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(ir);
            String message = br.readLine();
            System.out.println(message);
            String[] received=message.split("~");
            f.console.append(received[1]+": requesting for "+received[0]+"\n");
            System.out.println(received[1]+": requesting for "+received[0]+"\n");
        }catch(IOException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**CLIENT**

```
public class Branch extends JFrame
{
    private static Socket socket;
    JPanel main=new JPanel();
    JPanel top=new JPanel();
    JPanel bot=new JPanel();
    JButton btnItem=new JButton("item");
    JButton btnGlstock=new JButton("glstock");
    JTextArea console=new JTextArea();
    JScrollPane scrollv=new JScrollPane(console);

    ActionListener item=new ActionListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            String ip="";
            String send="";
            try
            {
                ip=InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();
                send="item~"+ip;
                request(send);
            }catch(Exception ex)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
    };

    ActionListener glstock=new ActionListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            String ip="";
            String send="";
            try
            {
                ip=InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();
                send="glstock~"+ip;
                request(send);
            }catch(Exception ex)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
    };

    private void request(String send)
    {
        try
        {
            OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
            OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);
            bw.write(send+"\n");
            bw.flush();
        }catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Branch()
    {
        super("Branch");
        scrollv.setAutoscrolls(true);
        main.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        top.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        top.add(btnItem);
        top.add(btnGlstock);
        btnItem.addActionListener(item);
        btnGlstock.addActionListener(glstock);
        bot.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        console.setEditable(false);
        console.setForeground(Color.white);
        console.setBackground(Color.black);
        bot.add(scrollv,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        main.add(top,BorderLayout.NORTH);
        main.add(bot,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(main);
    }

   private void connect2Server() throws IOException
   {
    Timer timer=new Timer(5000,checkPing);

    try
    {
        socket = new Socket(IP,port);
        console.append("You are now Connected to the Server\r\n");
        //timer.start();
        socket.setSoTimeout(5000);
        InputStreamReader isr=new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
        isr.read();
    }
    catch(SocketTimeoutException ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(IOException ex)
    {
        console.append("Server is offline\r\n");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    connect2Server();
  }

    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
        Branch frame=new Branch();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.connect2Server();
        frame.connectDatabase();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> How can I continuously ping the server, to determine if the server is up?

Use a timer of some sort to schedule a regular callback and make your test there.  Pinging a server (in this context) could be as simply as trying to make a connection to it...

You could also use [`InetAddress#isReachable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#isReachable(int)) as well...

> Why is it when I click the button the server can only receive once

Because the server is no longer processing your connection.  Take a look at your server code...

```
while(true)
{
    //^Reading the message from the client
    // Wait for a NEW client connection
    socket = serverSocket.accept();
    // Process request...
    InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
    String message = br.readLine();
    System.out.println(message);
    String[] received=message.split("~");
    console.append(received[1]+": requesting for "+received[0]+"\n");
    // ... No longer monitoring for new content...
}
```

`serverSocket.accept();` is waiting for a NEW client connection, not monitoring existing connections.

What you should be doing is spawning of a `Thread` of some kind, passing a reference to the client `Socket` connection and processing it there, within it's own loop...providing either a timeout or possible exit condition so that the socket and thread can be closed...

> Determine when the Server is disconnected

Basically, if you try and send something to the server (or client), it will throw some kind of `Exception`, which is a pretty good indication that the connection has disconnected for some reason.

You could, also, use some kind of timer to periodically send a "health" check message to the server, but, you would need to ensure that you are synchronizing your communications, so two (client side) threads don't try and send a message at the same time.

### Side Note

Your current code will block the Event Dispatching Thread when sending messages.  This might not be a big thing when you test locally, but, depending on the speed of the connection and the ability for the server to respond in a timely manner, could lead to your UI appearing to "freeze" for a second or two (or longer)

Have a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details

**Updated with example**

In order to allow you server to be able to handle multiple client connections, you need to spawn a new thread for each new connection, for example...

```
private void runServer() throws IOException
{
    int port = 25000;
    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
    console.setText("Server is Up and listening to the port: "+port+"\n");
    System.out.println("Server is Up and listening to the port: "+port+"\n");

    while(true)
    {
        Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Handler(socket));
        thread.start();
    }
}
```

Then in your "client socket handler", you need to setup a loop which will keep reading from the client socket until something goes wrong or the client requests that the communication been terminated, for example...

```
class Handler implements Runnable 
{
    private Socket socket;
    public Handler(Socket socket){
        this.socket = socket;
    }

    public void run() 
    {
        // You may need to add a repeat and exit clause here...
        try
        {
            boolean keepRunning = true;
            while (keepRunning) {
                InputStreamReader ir = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(ir);
                String message = br.readLine();
                System.out.println(message);
                String[] received=message.split("~");
                System.out.println(received[1]+": requesting for "+received[0]+"\n");
                // Check for a valid "exit" state and change keepRunning
                // if the client want's to disconnect...
            }
        }catch(IOException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (socket != null) {
                    socket.close();
                }
            } catch (Exception exp) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also, make sure you are closing your resources properly ;)

Comment: master @MadProgrammer sorry I don't know how to thread what should I do? because my previous programs I only `connect2Server` when I send files, now I have to `connect2Server` every second to determine if I lost or connected to the server.

Comment: Then it's probably time to start looking at [Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/), for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19152527/java-socket-programing/19152790#19152790)

Comment: master @MadProgrammer `while(running)` is that the same with a `while(true)` loop?

Comment: Not really, as you can change the state of `running` if your need to (from within the program)...I'm old school that way...

Comment: master I've updated the post, see the Server code is that it? I really don't know much sorry for being a total noob

Comment: ok i'll try ur codes master ((: I've tried to run my post then my computer hangs up ahahaha

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59078/discussion-between-askmaniac-and-madprogrammer).

Comment: master @MadProgrammer it's now working :D thx , but how do I put the received message to the JTextArea(console)
see edit :D on Handler part

Comment: Based on my understanding to your code, you would need a reference to the frame in order to make that call...

Comment: what reference? in the Handler class, I tried to call the console(Jtextarea) by `Server f=new Server(); f.console.append("text");`

Comment: No, based on you code `Handler` is not a internal class to server, so it can't access the same variables.  You need to pass a reference of the `JTextArea` to `Handler`, just like you did the socket.  You might better off putting together a runnable example and posting another question

Comment: Using `isReachable()` is pointless. It doesn't tell you whether the connect is actually going to succeed. Only actually trying to connect does that. You can't predict the future.

Comment: @EJP Checking for two states, machine reachable and process reachable.  I agree, just trying to open a connection will tell you both, but the OP seems to want to know the separate states

Comment: He can get it from the exception, if he cares. 'Connection refused' => server host is up, server isn't running. 'Connection timeout' => server host is down or firewall is misconfigured, but he doesn't actually need it: it doesn't make any difference to what he has to do next, which is to sleep and reconnect.

Comment: @MadProgrammer should I create a new thread for sending a file?
cause what will happen is when the client sends "item" to the SERVER, the server will be sending back a file to the branch

Comment: @askManiac All your comms should be done a spearate thread to start with.  The answer will depend on whether you will allow additional communications to occur while the file is been downloaded...

Comment: sorry, what are comms? and what do you mean by additional communications?

Comment: @askManiac Yes "comm"unication"s" ;).  If while the file is downloading, can the client talk with the server?  If you're doing this over a single socket, the server shouldn't write the output stream while it's writing the file contents, otherwise you'll end up with mixed content in your stream...messy...

Comment: ahaha sorry, well what I did was , when the client sends the message "item" to the server, A Thread Handler will receive it and in that thread will call another thread to create the file. so I was wondering if I should create another thread to send back a file or I can just use the Handler thread to send back the file

Comment: oohh so I can use another port socket to send the file?

Comment: @askManiac Personally, I'd isolate who can read/write to the underlying socket, as this could quickly mess things up.  If the client can't request a new item while it's downloading a previous request then it makes no difference, keep it to the same thread and get some in built safety around the I/O.  If on the other hand, you want to allow the client to make multiple requests (and potentially have multiple files), then you might need to consider an alternative design...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59248/discussion-between-madprogrammer-and-askmaniac).

Comment: master @MadProgrammer I've tried to setup 2 ports one on 4000 (for messages) and one on 25000 (for files) but everytime I'm trying to send the file it says connection has been refused

Comment: Is the server trying to connect to the client or visa-versa

Answer (score 0):

> How can I continuously ping the server, to determine if the server is up?

Keep trying to connect to it, with a sleep and loop if you fail.

> Why is it when I click the button the server can only receive once.

Because your server only reads once per connection. The `Handler.run()` method needs to loop until `readLine()` returns `null` or an exception occurs.

> Determine when the Server is disconnected

A `read()` would return -1, `readLine()` would return null, any other `readXXX()` will throw `EOFException.` However your client never reads at all. You should probably adjust your application protocol so that the server replies to each send. Otherwise you will just have to wait until an `IOException` occurs when sending, which could take several iterations before it happens due to TCP buffering.

Other notes:

1. Don't create new streams per send. Use the same streams, readers, writers, for the life of the socket.
2. Don't execute network code in the event thread. Use a separate thread.

Comment: Thank u @EJP
I followed MadProgrammer, I used the `address.isReachable(5000);` statement in a `Timer` 

and I finally made the Handler thread work! but I can't append the JTextArea.

Comment: Using isReachable() is pointless. It doesn't tell you whether the connect is actually going to succeed. Only actually trying to connect does that. You can't predict the future.

Comment: oh... EJP how would I do the `read()` thing ((: I really have no Idea sorry but would it be ok if you post a sample code :D

Comment: Set a read timeout with `Socket.setSoTimeout()`, and catch the `SocketTimeoutException` that results when the timeout happens. Set it high, e.g. double the expected response time, so it only happens when there really is a problem.

Comment: you mean `InputStreamReader isr=new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream)
isr.read();` ?

Comment: *However* you read, if you set a read timeout as I showed, you will get the exception I mentioned if it expires.

Comment: ok, so in the exception should I put connect2Server(); command there? so it will try to reconnect the server?

Comment: Don't put it into the `catch` block, put it at the top of a loop that is continued by the `catch (SocketTimeoutException exc)` block, directly or indirectly.

Comment: huh? but InputStreamReader requires to be in a try catch?

Comment: I didn't say anything about not putting `new InputStreamReader` inside a `try` block. You aren't making sense. Just do what I actually said, not what you think I said.

Comment: wait I'm sorry ahaha getting crazy here :D hahaha sorry.. I've read it wrong

Comment: Just calm down and do one thing at a time.

Comment: I updated the code, see CLIENT connect2Server(); is that how it's supposed to be?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59158/discussion-between-askmaniac-and-ejp).

Comment: No chat. I don't understand your code. You're setting the socket timeout and then reading a single character and throwing it away. Why? And your server is never sending you anything to read anyway. It doesn't make sense.

Comment: hm ok sorry... I'll try to fix it first...
so does this mean I have to make the server also send a message to the client?

Comment: should I create a new thread for replying with file?

cause when the branch asks for item the server would be sending a file back the client